# Ship tera templates in a crate without embedding them into the binary

Tags: templates, rust, tera

I am using [tera](https://github.com/Keats/tera) and want to make a CLI that acts as a new project generator (think `rails scaffold`). There will be quite a few templates and I would like to ship them in my crate as an asset file and read from disk instead of using `include_str!` and embedding the strings directly in the resulting binary.

Are there any crates that use this strategy that I could maybe reference? Is it possible to ship non-rust assets in a crate and have the referenced on disk later?

Comment: Might be worth looking at [`cargo generate`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-generate) even if it doesn't use `tera`.

Comment: I took a look. It seems that cargo generate doesn't ship with any templates, you have to provide them yourself like `cargo generate cargo generate username-on-github/mytemplate`

Comment: i'm surprised this is the only post i could find asking this question, it seems like a very common need to me ! why is there 0 traction on this ?

Comment: I did ask on issues https://github.com/Keats/tera/issues/788 as well. It might be possible to hack something together with that other crate I mentioned there, but I've not tried. You might end up with a problem of detecting if you're in "development" or "crate/deployment" mode.

Comment: I posted an issue on the cargo repos and got some answers that might help you ! https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/11683